# vb.net web application threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance, web-applications, backgroundworker

I have some functions in a web application that do a lot of calculations and as a result have high CPU usage which affects the rest of the application when other users are accessing it.

I have tried backgroundworker to no avail , the only thing that seems to work in using another thread and setting the priority to low, can the UI be updated from a worker thread? specifically I am trying to bind a grid to a dataset processed in the worker thread

Answer (score 0):

If you call [Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) periodically to process the windows message queue, this will allow the UI to be updated and respond to user input.

You need to understand that many people consider DoEvents to be evil.  As the UI will respond to events such as click, you should beware of any issues this can cause such as allowing many of your heavy CPU BackgroundWorker threads to be spawned.  However, used correctly DoEvents provides a valid strategy for keeping your application responsive during processing.